# date field in solr not indexing proper date from sitecore

Tags: solr, content-search

i am changing search from lucene to solr and faced an issue in this , i have DateTime a field in sitecore and an item is using that field and have value of now 
 ( DATE -- 4/4/2019 TIME -- 12:00 AM) but when i have rebuild the indexing , in solr that field ( **date_tdt** ) is not giving the same value as declared in sitecore rather it is showing **date_tdt = "2014-11-05T00:00:00Z"** ,  i dont know why it is showing some other date and when i am generating query to match that date  using Date `filterSearch = filterSearch.And(x => x.Date >= DateTime.Now.ToUniversalTime());` 
it is generating  `date_tdt:[2019-04-04T17:53:34.483Z TO *]` in the search log .
Don`t know why it is happening .

Comment: If I'm understanding you correctly it sounds like you have a discrepancy in the date - you're expecting 4/4/2019 and seeing 5/11/2014. Are you sure you're looking at the right item in Solr? What does your query look like?

Answer (score 1):

Dates are stored as UTC. What you are seeing is the value with timezone information.

I would suggest you check the raw field value and then make sure your field is actually crawled.